# OxyPlot: AngleAxis labels rotation in Polar Plots

Tags: c#, wpf, plot, oxyplot

When an AngleAxis is created, the associated labels are rotated depending on the axes angles. Is it possible to choose a different angle rotation for those labels, for example, make them horizontal (no rotation)?
​
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's been awhile since I've used OxyPlot, but  all the various types of axis have an `Angle` property which will do just that. When you create your `AngleAxis` set `Angle` to 0.

Comment: I did that, but it doesn't work. When I set `Angle` to a value different from zero the `MagniteAxes` gets rotated. I thought that I was doing something wrong but I changed the Angle property in the Polar Plot demo in Oxyplot repository, and I got the same result: the `MagniteAxes` got rotated and nothing happens to `AngleAxis`.

Comment: @juliomrqz Can you post your code and I will see if I can help.

Comment: Is there any update on this? I'm having the exact same problem...